# Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:8080/PSWebServices/services/EmpDetails

Tags: web-services, backbone.js

Hi I am facing the issue while accessing the Response from Restful WS  using Backbone.

I have created a WS on my local machine where I am returning the JSON Array

```
            JSONArray empDataJsonArray = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject empData = new JSONObject();
    try
    {   
        empData.put("id", emp.getEmpId());
        empData.put("firstname", emp.getfName());
        empData.put("lastname", emp.getlName());
        empData.put("age", emp.getrCount());
        empData.put("City", emp.getCity());
        empData.put("Country", emp.getCountry());
    }
    catch(JSONException jsonEx) {
        throw jsonEx;
    }
    return empDataJsonArray.put(empData);
```

When I access my WS from the browse.

```
 http://localhost:8080/PSWebServices/services/EmpDetails
```

I get the result as 
[{"id":"033451","firstname":"Naveen","lastname":"Kapoor","age":10,"City":"Bangalore","Country":"India"}]

But when I am trying to access the same from Backbone code

```
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    options.url = 'http://localhost:8080/PSWebServices/services' + options.url;
});

var Users = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : '/EmpDetails'
});

var UserList = Backbone.View.extend({
el:".page",
render:function(){
var that = this;
 var users = new Users();
 users.fetch({
 success: function(m,r){
      console.log("success");
      console.log(r); // => 2 (collection have been populated)
    },
    error: function(m,r) {
      console.log("error");
      console.log('error arguments: ', arguments);
    }
                 });
             }
        });
```

While debugging on firefox in network tab I can see the 200 OK response.
    OPTIONS EmpDetails
    200 OK
    578 B
with header response as below : 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: OPTIONS,HEAD,GET
Content-Type: application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Content-Length: 578
Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 06:30:48 GMT

But when I look for the response I can see the below message
"Reload the page to get source for:

```
http://localhost:8080/PSWebServices/services/EmpDetails"
```

When I added the arguments in console log to see the error I see xhr status is as below. Need help on what is missing.
    xhr: Object { readyState=4, status=404, statusText="error", more...}

readyState :    4
responseJSON :  undefined
status : 404
statusText : "error"

Comment: It looks like you're not returning JSON from the API: "application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml"

Comment: Hi David... I am using the below code to get the response as JSON

    @Path("/EmpDetails")
    public interface EmployeeDetails {
 
 @GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
 public Response getEmployeeDetails(@QueryParam("empId") String Id);

    }

Comment: @DavidSulc above is the code I have used for JSON response

Comment: @DavidSulc Noticed one more thing when I am hitting this url directly in the browser I am getting the correct result and the content type is also application/json
header info :
Content-Type application/json
Date Tue, 25 Mar 2014 13:08:18 GMT
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding chunked
and response as below :
{"id":"033451","firstname":"Naveen","lastname":"Kapoor","age":10,"City":"Bangalore","Country":"India"}